# Batch File Setting an Environment Variable

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I currently have this code in my batch file to store a value in variable %%i:

```
FOR /F %%i in (AylaUnits.txt) DO set %%i 
set "$Unit=%%i"
echo The unit is : %$Unit%
Pause
```

This seems to loop fine, but for each item I get this response:

```
set AC000W000004591
Environment variable AC000W000004595 not defined
The unit is : %i
```

There is going to be 100+ different lines in the text file. Will I need to create an environmental variables for each one? I don't think that's the best way to do it and I'm not sure I'm understanding environmental variables correctly.

I need to plug each line of the file into a url section if that's of any importance.

Thanks,
DM

Comment: what is supposed to be the output?

Comment: The output should show each item in the list as a test. I want to eventually plug them into this line: curl -H "Authorization: auth_token %$token%" https://ads-dev.aylanetworks.com/apiv1/devices/%$Unit%/properties/%$PropertyKey%/datapoints.xml?limit=100>AylaData.xml   I just couldn't get the syntax right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax issue, see the proposed change below:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F %%i in (AylaUnits.txt) DO (
    set "$Unit=%%i"
    echo The unit is : !$Unit!
)
Pause
```

Please see the edit above, since we're setting the variable inside the `for` loop, we need to use `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` to be able to expand on it.  Since we're expanding the var that's set in the `for` loop, we need to use `!` instead of `%` when using those variables.

Comment: Thank you that is helpful. Is echo The unit is : %$Unit% not part of the FOR loop since it only shows the last line? Or is that what it is supposed to do?

Comment: @user3757643 That's the expected result, please see the new edit that will give you echo every instance

Comment: you're right that does work better. This might be a dumb question, but if I had SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION in the batch file that calls this batch file do I still need to set it in this file?

Comment: It's not a dumb question, it should pass to your other batch file.  Just be careful, since it kind of changes the way the interpreter interprets the syntax check out the link for some more details: http://judago.webs.com/variablecatches.htm